# Postgres: using 9999-12-31 vs NULL as expire date

Tags: postgresql, date, indexing, null

In a Postgres table, I'm storing some events with their `expire_date`. I'm wondering how to model non-expiring events. Two alternatives:

1. `expire_date = 9999-12-31`
2. `expire_date = NULL`

The column `expire_date` will be indexed. From the performance perspective, are there any differences between the two approaches?

Comment: Don't use nonsense values to mean "no value". Use `NULL`, as it explicitly means *no value*.

Comment: My question comes from this [doc](https://github.com/bmoeskau/Extensible/blob/master/recurrence-overview.md#storage-and-retrieval) where they say: "date should always contain valid date/time values (not null)". I believed that it was for performance reasons

Comment: NULL means there is no knowledge available about the expire_date. It could expire, or not, you just don't know. When you know that an event will not expire, you shouldn't use NULL because now you do know that it won't expire. But you also have "infinity", that tells you exactly what you want to know. Check also the function isfinite() for selecting records with the value infinity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that column is used for range queries, storing `NULL` is a problem because you always need an `OR` condition which can be bad for performance.

But luckily, Postgres provides a DATE value that is bigger then all others: `infinity` so you can store that for the expire_date.

e.g.

```
insert into events (id, ..., expire_date)
values (1, ..., 'infinity');
```

Note that the opposite `-infinity` also exists. It also works for `timestamp` columns.

---

A range query on a NULL value could be indexed, if you use `coalesce()` instead of an OR condition:

```
create index on events (coalesce(expire_date, 'infinity'))
```

But you need to use that exact expression in your queries in order to make use of that index, e.g:

```
select *
from events
where coalesce(expire_date, 'infinity') > date '2022-08-01'
```

When storing `infinity` instead of `NULL`, you don't need to remember that in your queries.

Comment: Oh great! So the problem lies in the OR condition for range queries. Got it!

Comment: @floatingpurr: you can actually avoid the OR, but that requires to index an expression and the index will only be used if you use that exact expression in your queries. See my edit

Comment: it looks like using infinity is way better